# Android how to set button to have transparent background but outline still there

Tags: android, button

When I set `android:background="@android:color/transparent`, it sets my buttons background to transparent, but the outline of the button disappears. How do I set it so that the background is transparent but there is still an outline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom selector that uses different nine patch image for different states of the button.

This [link](http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2009/12/android-selectors.html) might be helpful

You might use this image...

[image]

I hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to make yourself a 9-patch that has a border but transparency in the middle.

Here is an example:

[image: Example 9-patch]

it is an 11x11 pixel square with a 2 pixel black border. If you download this png and drop it into draw9patch and add the a pixel in the middle of the left and top then include the 9patch png file in your drawables and set

```
android:background="@drawable/bground"
```

either save your 9-patch as "bground" or change that in the above line to whatever you save it as.